# Replace node in XML in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to replace below node

```
 <Test>
        <Test.1>1</Test.1>
        <Test.2>ABC</Test.2>
        <Test.3>XXX</Test.3>
   </Test>
```

So If my input XML has Test node then "Test" node-name should be replace with node name as "aaa"
Output should be like:

```
<aaa>
            <aaa.1>1</aaa.1>
            <aaa.2>ABC</aaa.2>
            <aaa.3>XXX</aaa.3>
 </aaa>
```

I have tried like:

```
 <xsl:when test="../name()='Test'">
     <aaa>
        <aaa.1>1</aaa.1>
        <aaa.2>ABC</aaa.2>
        <aaa.3>XXX</aaa.3>             
     </aaa>       

   </xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `substring-after()` to get the rest of the name and create the new one...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(local-name(),'Test')]">
    <xsl:element name="aaa{substring-after(local-name(),'Test')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you want to change node name starting with *Test*,
replacing *Test* with *aaa*.

To perform this task you need a template matching elements,
which names start with *Test*.
It can be made using a predicate in `match` attribute:

```
match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Test')]"
```

The content of this template should include:

- Create a new element, with changed name (*aaa* + the "rest"
  of the tag name).
- Apply templates to the content of the current element,
  like in the *identity template*.
- Close the just created element.

Of course, the script should include also the *identity template*.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'Test')]">
    <xsl:element name="aaa{substring(name(), 5)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```